# Is there a difference between waiting for a Task and waiting for the Result of a ContinueWith?

Tags: c#, multithreading

i.e. Is there any difference between how task 1 and task 2 block and do they interact in the same way with the Thread Pool?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t1 = Task.Run<int>(() => GiveMeAOne());
        var t2 = Task.Run<int>(() => GiveMeAOne());

        t1.Wait();
        Debug.WriteLine(t1.Result);

        Debug.WriteLine(t2.ContinueWith(r => r.Result).Result);

    }

    public static int GiveMeAOne()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Task.wait and continueWIth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490339/task-wait-and-continuewith)

Comment: Simply look at the confirmed answered on the post above

Comment: That answer talks about async, await, and deadlocks, not about how ContinueWith is implemented.  It looks like every question about Wait() is answered with "use async, not Wait" even if that isn't what is being asked.

Comment: I believe this code won't deadlock the UI thread as it's a console application. I have based that on this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `t2` you are blocking on the continuation of `t2`. Continuations can run inline as part of task completion or they can run as separate thread-pool work items. This difference is immaterial, though. In all cases one thread will be blocked waiting.

Note, that `r.Result` always returns without blocking but `t2.ContinueWith(r => r.Result).Result` blocks on the continuation.